# Why do I get a syntax error when I use raw_input in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do:

```
raw_input("Anyone Home?")
```

But I'm getting syntax error! I'm using Python 3, is this another thing that one can only do in Python 2?

Comment: Please do a ___Python 3___ tutorial, and read http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html, or download Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
input("Hello?")
```

That is a Python 3 command, while

```
raw_input("Hello?")
```

is a Python 2 command

If the book that you are using only has Python 2 things, get a new book!